# ng-class with nested property

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have troubles with using `ng-class` with nested properties:

This work

```
ng-class="{'fullscreen': isFullScreen()}"
```

This doesn't work

```
ng-class="{'fullscreen': vm.isFullScreen()}"
```

Am I missing something obvious? I don't have any problems with other directives like `ng-if` or `ng-switch`

Here is a js fiddle that explains the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/4Efz4/2

Comment: What is `vm`? Also, any errors in the console?

Comment: vm is a pojo i define on the scope. if I define the `isFullscreen()` function directly on the scope (and I use the second snippet) it works  correctly, if I define a vm object on the scope with the `isFullScreen()` function (and use the first snippet) it doesn't. Let me setup a jsfiddle to be clear

Comment: Nothing obvious from what you have posted.  Can you show the relevant bits from the controller?

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/4Efz4/1/

Comment: Yes there was a typo in my jsfiddle. I guess my real problem is with typescript and not in ng-class then...

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

saw that you commented a JSFiddle, your example works fine

[image]

---

http://jsfiddle.net/88nut/

view:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TestingCtrl">

                <div ng-repeat="p in persons">

                    <input ng-model="p.name" ng-class="{'fancy' : p.isFullScreen()}">
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
function TestingCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.persons = [{
        name: 'Alice',
        isFullScreen: function()
        {
            return false;
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Bob',
        isFullScreen: function()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }];

}
```

css:

```
.fancy{
    background:Yellow;
}
```